# Drag and toggle button in GWT like Ubuntu 12.04 toggle button

Tags: java, gwt, animation, button

How can i create a button( or widget) which can be toggled by dragging it in GWT? Do we have any in-built function in GWT for this ?

Comment: Attach a screenshot and Share a link if you are looking for particular behaviour.

Comment: Well its just a normal button.I wanna create a on/off button like iPhone buttons.

Comment: I am guessing its something like this - http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/352_toggle/demo.html Along with slide and not just click. Reference http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/creating-a-javascript-free-radio-toggle-in-css3/

Comment: @SSR I went through the article. Was great and impressive. But my requirement is that i wanna change the state by dragging also, not just only by clicking.

Comment: You have a "OR" in your question :) .

Comment: You will get some ideas here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596807/converting-gwt-click-events-to-touch-events

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by toggling by dragging, but as far as widgets are concerned, you have a few options.

1. The [GWT widget gallery](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefWidgetGallery) is a nice overview of basic gwt widgets.
2. You can create your own widget extending a gwt widget such as [`ToggleButton`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ToggleButton.html) and write extended functionality you need.
3. There's a good chance a widget library has what you're looking for. A good place to look is [Sencha's ext-gwt library](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt), it has great examples too.